# Avoid sending object properties not set on an auto-generated class from xml serializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have imported a WSDL from a third party Java web service. One of the methods requires a ComplexType object, that was serialized into a class on C# when I imported the WSDL. The WSDL is as follows:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="MethodReturn">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="param1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="param2" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="param3" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="param4" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

When I send the Method, I'm getting the error below:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.teste.webservice.model.MethodReturn - param3
```

The third party developer told me that I shouldn't send the `param3` property along the serialized XML when I send the method. How can I accomplish this using C#? If I set MethodReturn=null, the property is included as xsil:nil="true", as follows:

```
  <param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">U</param1>
  <param2 xsi:type="xsd:string">2032290</param2>
  <param3 xsi:nil="true"/>
  <param4 xsi:type="xsd:string">EU1</param4>
```

What I would like to do is not to send `param3` at all, like below. Is that possible?

```
  <param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">U</param1>
  <param2 xsi:type="xsd:string">2032290</param2>
  <param4 xsi:type="xsd:string">EU1</param4>
```

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well either the 3rd party developer or the WSDL is wrong.  If the WSDL is wrong, then edit it:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MethodReturn">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="param1" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
  <xsd:element name="param2" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
  <xsd:element name="param3" type="xsd:string" />
  <xsd:element name="param4" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:sequence>
```

Comment: if I ask the third party developer to remove the nillable="true", and I don't supply anything, the param3 won't be serialized, and sent over? Tks

Comment: Yes that is correct.  The way they specify param3 in WSDL says that it must be included.

Comment: Ok, I'll send it in. Tks for your time and answer!